# Can I make the local "this" available inside another function?

Tags: javascript

I have this function coded:

```
var Dom = function () {

    this.getX = function (element, value) {
        ... 
    }

    this.checkX = function (label, expectedCount, params) {
        it(label + ': Check for ' + expectedCount, function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; ++i) {
                this.getX.apply(this, params[i]).click();
            }
        });
    }
```

It gives me an undefined with getX.  How can I make it so the getX will work inside the checkX function?

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: A note: To me it looks like the `it()` of mocha, but the way you use it looks really strange to me. Maybe it is not mocha but if it is you should check if you really use it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can change what `this` refers to in a function, or otherwise retain access to the outer `this`. However, we should note that your problem is not with `checkX`, but with the anonymous function *within* `checkX`, so you need to apply one of these techniques to that function.

Storing a reference to `this` in a variable:

```
var Dom = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.getX = function(element, value) {
        ...
    }

    this.checkX = function (label, expectedCount, params) {
        it(label + ': Check for ' + expectedCount, function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; ++i) {
                self.getX.apply(self, params[i]).click();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Or using [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (thanks to elclanrs for mentioning this in the comments):

```
var Dom = function() {
    this.getX = function(element, value) {
        ...
    };

    this.checkX = function (label, expectedCount, params) {
        it(label + ': Check for ' + expectedCount, (function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; ++i) {
                this.getX.apply(this, params[i]).click();
            }
        }).bind(this));
    }
}
```

..Or, by using [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). This technique won't work in your scenario because you don't control when the anonymous function is called, but it's useful to know in general.

```
var Dom = function() {
    this.getX = function(element, value) {
        ...
    };

    this.checkX = function (label, expectedCount, params) {
        ...
    }

    // when calling checkX later..
    this.checkX.call(this, argument1, argument2, argument3);
}
```

Many JavaScript libraries contain utilities to easily handle what `this` refers to, since callback functions are incredibly common in most JS applications. For example, see [`dojo.hitch`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/hitch.html) or jQuery's [`$.proxy`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/). You can easily write your own function to do the same:

```
function WrapCallbackWithContext(context, callback) {
    return function() {
        return callback.apply(context, arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP has the problem because of the inner closure. In your examples, how you wrote it, you don't need it, `this` will refer to the instance inside `this.checkX`. The problem arises when you introduce another scope.

Comment: @elclanrs Quite right - I just submitted an edit for that reason.

Comment: oooooo.... how much I hate `that = this`... I find it causes much unnecessary confusion... Why would you refer to the current "instance" as "that" from within itself? IMO, `self` is the only sane alternative for `this`.

Comment: @Lix That's probably a much better choice. I almost never use that idiom myself, preferring to bind `this` in other ways, so I just used the first thing that came to mind. I'll go ahead and change to `self` in case anyone stumbles on this from google though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try preserving the scope in a different variable:

```
var Dom = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.getX = function ( element, value ) {
        ... 
    }

    this.checkX = function ( label, expectedCount, params ) {
        ...
        self.getX.apply( self, params[ i ] ).click();
        ... 
    }
}
```

`var self = this;` preserves the scope of your `DOM` function inside the `self` variable. When you get into one of the inner functions, you'll still have access to the `self` variable and hence still have access to the original scope.

Comment: I think it should be also `.apply(self` and not `.apply(this`.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your `it` function is calling a `callback` function and inside `callback` `this` will not refer to your outer function

```
var Dom = function () {

    this.getX = function (element, value) {
        ... 
    }
    var _this = this;
    this.checkX = function (label, expectedCount, params) {
        it(label + ': Check for ' + expectedCount, function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; ++i) {
                _this.getX.apply(this, params[i]).click();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's rather uncommon that `this` refers to function itself, so I doubt that `this` refers to `callback`.